# Solving the recurrence $g(n)=g(n-1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ with $g(0)=0$

Tags: recurrence-relations, puzzle

I ran across the following math puzzle: a mouse is on a circle with circumference of 100 units and every turn he walks on the circle a unit of 1 after every turn the circle is increased by 100 units (evenly distributed) will the mouse ever reach the end.

To solve this, I came up with the following distance equation for the mouse:

> $$g(n)=g(n-1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
>
> $$g(0)=0$$
>
> How does one go about solving this equation?

Comment: Shouldn't your initial condition be $g(1)=0$ ?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze the function describes the mouse distance in units at each turn, my definition of turn 0 is before any turns were made, hence the mouse moved 0 units at turn 0,

Comment: @  Mike How do you then calculate $g(1)$ from the recursion? My solution is $g(n) = n H_{n-1}$ ($H_n$ the harmonic number). The values of $g(n)$ for $n=0 ..5$ are $\left\{-1,0,2,\frac{9}{2},\frac{22}{3},\frac{125}{12}\right\}$. Here $g(0)$ has to be understood as a limiting value.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze its a matter of definition, I defined the function $g(n) = (n+1)H_n$ which shifts the above values left one, retaining the $g(0)=0$

Comment: @ Mike That is just what I was saying. You should do the shift in the first place. Otherwise (I repeat) your recurrence leads to infinity for g(1).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze sorry, i missed that, you are absolutely correct. in my notes the function was denoted $g(n) = g(n-1) (1+1/n)+(1+1/n)$ where $g(0)=0$ which works as expected. i must of mixed up the index when typing the question, will edit question, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95097/discussion-between-mike-and-dr-wolfgang-hintze).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

$$
ng_{n+1}=(n+1)g_n+n+1\Rightarrow \frac{g_{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{g_n}{n}+\frac 1n
$$

now calling $f_n = \frac{g_n}{n}$ we have

$$
f_{n+1} = f_n +\frac 1n
$$

for $n > 0$

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @Cesareo's answer
$$f_{n+1} = f_n +\frac 1n \implies f_n=\psi (n)+\gamma+c$$ where appears the digamma function. So

$$g_n=n\left(\psi (n)+\gamma+c \right)$$ but the condition should be something else than $g_0=0$.

If it is $g(1)=0$, then $c=0$.

Comment: Lebovici: It would be nice to mention that $f(n)$ is in fact in the form of a first-order harmonic number (up to the additive constant $C$). In fact, $\psi (n)+\gamma =H_{n-1}$ with $H_m:=\sum_{i=1}^{m}1/i$.

Comment: @MarianG. You are totally correct. I shall not edit my naswer on purpose just to show how stupid I can be. Cheers :-(

Comment: Sorry for your name distortion.